# Finite group with squarefree order has periodic cohomology?

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-cohomology

Is it true that a finite group with squarefree order has periodic group cohomology (with trivial coefficients)?

I cannot see why this would be the case, but I'm looking at a paper which seems to implicitly say it's true [Vogel, ON STEENROD'S PROBLEM FOR NON ABELIAN FINITE GROUPS, p.1].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All subgroups are then squarefree, and by FTAG all such abelian subgroups are cyclic. Now, a group has periodic cohomology iff all its abelian subgroups are cyclic (Theorem VI.9.5 of Brown's book) -- this is proved by first reducing to Sylow p-subgroups.

Comment: @NeilStrickland Can you clarify? If you'd like a rephrasing, first note that all Sylow subgroups of a squarefree group are cyclic, and then again by Theorem VI.9.5 that's equivalent to the group having periodic cohomology.

Comment: Sorry, the statement that I was complaining about was a slightly different statement than the one that you actually made.  I will delete my earlier comment.